# toggle JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I just want a simple toggle js, so when you click on About in the nav the about text appears, but it's now working oO

JS part:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function toggle() {
var about = document.getElementById('about')
if(about.style.display = "none")
{
about.style.display = "block";
}

else
{
about.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<header>
...
    <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:toggle()" onClick="toggle()">About me</a></li>
        ...more <li>s...
    </ul></nav>
</header>
<br/>

<div id="about">
aboutme
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#about {
    display: none;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Also, don't put `javascript:toggle()` in the `href` of the link.

Comment: `<a href="#" onClick="toggle()">`?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. But if you only use that element for JavaScript, you should rather use a button and style it as a link if you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In if statement you have to `have two equal sign`

```
function toggle() {
    var about = document.getElementById('about');
    if(about.style.display == "none")
    {
        about.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        about.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**Note**

```
= you can just assign value to variable
== must be used to compare variables values
=== must be used to compare variables in every aspect (In type too)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the `==` problem, and then instead of hiding your "about" element with that CSS rule put the style directly on the element:

```
<div id=about style='display: none'>About Me</div>
```

If you don't do that, the JavaScript code won't see that "display" property on the style object. (The style object only reflects styles directly associated with the element, not those controlled by CSS stylesheets.)